# Python выделить слово из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть список

'''147                         Прямой эфир канала МАТЧ ПРЕМЬЕР\n155        Ростов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 2 тур\n158        Тамбов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 3 тур\n165                         Прямой эфир канала МАТЧ ПРЕМЬЕР\n173        Ростов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 2 тур\n                                ...                        \n366608     Арсенал - Динамо. Российская Премьер-лига. 1 тур\n366619     Ростов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 2 тур\n366626     Тамбов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 3 тур\n366628                      Прямой эфир канала МАТЧ ПРЕМЬЕР\n366638    Локомотив - Тамбов. Российская Премьер-лига. 2...\nName: title, Length: 41692, dtype: object'''

Из этого списка надо выделить только названия команд. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярками, например:

```py
import re

text = '''147 Прямой эфир канала МАТЧ ПРЕМЬЕР\n155 Ростов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 2 тур\n158 Тамбов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 3 тур\n165 Прямой эфир канала МАТЧ ПРЕМЬЕР\n173 Ростов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 2 тур\n ... \n366608 Арсенал - Динамо. Российская Премьер-лига. 1 тур\n366619 Ростов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 2 тур\n366626 Тамбов - Спартак. Российская Премьер-лига. 3 тур\n366628 Прямой эфир канала МАТЧ ПРЕМЬЕР\n366638 Локомотив - Тамбов. Российская Премьер-лига. 2...\nName: title, Length: 41692, dtype: object'''

rx = re.compile(r'\d+\s+(\w+\s+-\s+\w+)')
rx.findall(text)
```

Вывод:

```
['Ростов - Спартак',
 'Тамбов - Спартак',
 'Ростов - Спартак',
 'Арсенал - Динамо',
 'Ростов - Спартак',
 'Тамбов - Спартак',
 'Локомотив - Тамбов']
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, стало лучше. Однако так показывается только 7 матчей(первые и последние), а в строке находится в районе 150-200 таких матчей. как можно сделать то же самое для всей строки?

Comment: Судя по выводу у вас вообще `pandas dataframe`, который вывели на экран и он при этом выводе обрезался, а на самом деле там 41692 строк данных. Так что мне кажется тут нужно начать с того, а что же у вас на самом деле есть? Из той строки, которую вы дали, регуляркой выводится всё, что там есть.